# Passing empty Array to ArrayAdapter.createResource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I have am initializing an array adapter like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), -1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

But unfortunately, I keeping receiving the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray
```

I think this is because I am passing `-1` as the lookup for my Array. The problem is I am creating the array programmatically AFTER this so I actually don't have a Array defined in R.Arrays.

Does anybody know how I can initialize the ArrayAdapter without having a defined Array XML file?

Comment: Why are you using `createFromResource` when you don't have Array defined in R.Arrays.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> listLoadToSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            mContext,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            listLoadToSpinner);
```

P.S : It's better to initialize the Adapter once you have the Array and set that Adapter to Spinner.